# I need a quotation environment which is italic by default, but my attempts to define an new evironment give errors

Tags: environments, italic, quotation

This does not compile, but I do not understand why:

```
\newenvironment{italicquote}{%
  \begin{quotation}\textit{%
}{%
  }\end{quotation}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Don.  I pasted the code as you edited it, but then it changed.

Comment: You need to select the code and click the `{}` button to format it as a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you're running into is that your braces aren't matching correctly. Here's what you have if we rearrange things to show where the braces are:

```
\newenvironment{italicquote}
{%
  \begin{quotation}\textit{%
                          }
  {%
  }
  \end{quotation}
}
```

Oops, there's only two arguments being given to `\newenvironment` instead of three. That's why it doesn't compile.

So how do we fix this? There are two options:

One is that we can use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` which give us a mechanism for putting unbalanced braces into definitions. This makes your environment definition into:

```
\newenvironment{italicquote}{%
  \begin{quotation}\textit\bgroup
}{%
  \egroup\end{quotation}
}
```

Another option is to use `\NewDocumentEnvironment`¹ instead of `\newenvironment to define the environment. With this, we can use the` +b`argument specifier to pass the entirety of the`italicquote`environment as an argument. The`+`indicates that we should allow it to have paragraphs in it. When we use`+b`we usually leave the definition of the`\end` command empty since everything can be done in the begin:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{italicquote}{ +b }{%
  \begin{quotation}
    \textit{#1}
  \end{quotation}
}{}
```

This does have the limitation that since we're taking the contents of the environment as an argument, we can't have, e.g., `\verb` inside the environment, although we couldn't do that with our first version either since the `\verb` would be passed in the argument to `\textit`.

So, what if we wanted to have the environment able to have `\verb` in it². Then we could use `\itshape`³ to select the italic shape. Since environments are in groups, the `\itshape` will go away at the end of the environment on its own. This gives us a clean definition of:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{italicquote}{}{%
  \begin{quotation}\itshape
}{%
  \end{quotation}%
}
```

I'm still not happy with this though. After all, `italicquote` isn't really a semantic markup concept and I probably would like to just have all my `quotation` environments in italic.

We *could* redefine `quotation` (and if you look through some of my other answers, you'll see some examination of how you could do that), but better still is to use LaTeX's hooks mechanism. We can use the `env/quotation/begin` hook to add the `\itshape` command to format the environment body. This would look like:

```
\AddToHook{env/quotation/begin}{\itshape}
```

and we get all of our `quotation` environments typeset in italics.

---

1. In general, we should prefer `\NewDocumentEnvironment` over `\newenvironment` and `\NewDocumentCommand` over `\newcommand`.
2. Or some other catcode-changing command. I'm not sure if the `+b` thing would break, e.g., `\url`. I suppose I could try it but it's late and I really should be sleeping instead of writing this.
3. `\textit{`…`}` is essentially the same as `{\itshape`…`\/}` where `\/` adds an italic correction at the end of the font change. Other than different semantics, the output is identical.

Comment: Adding \AddToHook{env/quotation/begin}{\itshape} to the .cls file causes an undefined control sequence error.

Comment: \NewDocumentEnvironment{italicquote}{}{%
  \begin{quotation}\itshape
}{%
  \end{quotation}%
} solved the problem, when the empty set of {} are removed and newenvironment is used instead of NewDocumentEnvironment.

Comment: Based on the errors that you report, it sounds like you have an older version of LaTeX on your system.

Comment: TeXLive on Debian 10.